# Ubuntu 22.04 English input language duplicates twice when switching input language

Tags: bug-reporting

I have only two input languages and I used Gnome Tweak tools to make alt+shift switching input languages. But when I cycle through them - I get English language selected twice.

I did many tests and it can not be a coincidence or misclick.

Pattern repeats many times.
`asdas dasdas фвівфі adsasd dsasda Фівфів adsdas Adsasdas Фівфівф sdasad dasdas вфівфі asdasd Adsasdas вфівфі'

See? I typed it just one time, it is impossible that I failed to switch to English 5 times in a row. There is got to be some bug or what?

Did anybody encounter this?

Comment: Remove English in Settings

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. Note that the comment "Remove English in Settings" is **NOT** a solution since it deactivates your keyboard shortcuts, making you unable to use them.

I guess, in fact, there must be some "hidden" English keyboard which Ubuntu provides, and which is not seen in the keyboards list.

**Update 1**

Now, I experimented with the impact of keyboard deletion on shortcuts once more. What I found was interesting:

*When I deleted the English keyboard, my custom defined shortcuts (all in the form of Ctrl+Alt+...) became deactivated, as expected. Next, I tried to see if redefining the shortcuts in this new setting would work. Although I was able to redefine a shortcut, the strangest issue was that the Right Alt key didn't work anymore!! I was only able to use Left Alt + Left Ctrl. However, adding the English keyboard again in Settings resolved this limitation.*

Based on the above observation, I have come to the conclusion that, that "hidden" English keyboard must have some limitations.

**Update 2**

Seems that I have identified the root cause of the duplication problem:

### The problem stems from alteration of the language switch from the default combination (Super + Space) to the tweaked version (such as Left Alt + Left Shift).

In fact, I re-activated the default key combination (Super + Space) besides the altered one. Now, what I observe is that cycling between languages using Super+Space is perfectly OK and with no English duplication, while the tweaked combination Alt+Shift is problematic and duplicates English. So, I conclude that the main problem is with Gnome Tweaks.

***Takeaway:  undo the Gnome tweak and return to the default key combination Super+Space.***